# Notation for multiple function outputs?

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to formulate the following in proper math notation, but I am not sure how to do so. Maybe you can help me with this.

I have a set of data `D` and some additional arguments `r_i` and a function `f`, that calculates 2 values `a` and `b` from this data. Basically I have `a, b = f(r_1, r_2, D)`.

How would you format this in proper math notation?

Comment: So $f$ maps into $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: $(a,b) = f(r_1,r_2,D)$

Comment: $f(r_1,r_2,D)=(a,b)$

Comment: I have never seen before this notation `(a,b)`. I thought you could only map one element by a function `f` in mathematics.

Comment: $(a,b)$ is a tuple.
Think of $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2$ as $a \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb R$ and $f(r_1, r_2, D) = (a,b)$ means that for given $r_1, r_2, D$ there is a pair of $a$ and $b$ (which we denote as $(a,b)$) that has the respective values.

Comment: *I have never seen before this notation* --- Points on the $xy$-coordinate plane? Vectors in high school trigonometry? Elements in the Cartesian product of two sets? Vector-valued functions in a beginning multivariable calculus course? See also the Wikipedia article for [Multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function).

Comment: Do we have a set $D$ of data $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_N)$ or a set of data $D=(d_1,\ldots, d_N)$?

Comment: Well, a (vector) and b (matrix) are from different types. Also D is a set of different information, more like a container, holding not just one kind of data fom domain R, but also different domains. From my understanding a function f in mathematics maps from one domain into the other. Is this still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a set $\Omega$ of data points $\omega$ and the parameter points $r=(r_1,r_2)\in{\mathbb R}^2$. You then are given two functions
$$f:\quad{\mathbb R}^2\times\Omega\to {\mathbb R}^n, \qquad(r,\omega)\to a(r,\omega)=\bigl(a_1(r,\omega),\ldots, a_n(r,\omega)\bigr)$$
and
$$g:\quad{\mathbb R}^2\times\Omega\to M_{m\times n}, \qquad(r,\omega)\to B(r,\omega)=\bigl[b_{ik}(r,\omega)\bigr]_{i\in[m],\> k\in[n]}\ .$$